# Something is wrong when i popViewController. Why?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 view controllers. Hierarchy is: Root->My_Account->Details. All controllers are navigation controller.
I have some images on My_Account. When i go back from Details, i see strange My_Account view. Some images invisible , some labels invisible too. But, why?
SOLVED

Comment: show some of the code you are using, or maybe a screenshot.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the contents of the My_Account view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.  State variable was incorrect.